# Is there way to import a spreadsheet with this data structure to neo4j to create the nodes and relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
NodeID  Module           Sub-Module         Menu        Sub Menu

1       Module 1        Sub Module 1        Menu 1      Sub Menu A

2       Module 1        Sub Module 1        Menu 1      Sub Menu A

3       Module 1        Sub Module 1        Menu 1      Sub Menu A

4       Module 1        Sub Module 1        Menu 1      Sub Menu A

5       Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

6       Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

7       Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

8       Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

9       Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

10      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

11      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

12      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

13      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

14      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

15      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

16      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

17      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 2      Sub Menu B

18      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 3      Sub Menu C

19      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 3      Sub Menu C

20      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 3      Sub Menu C

21      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 3      Sub Menu C

22      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 3      Sub Menu C

23      Module 1        Sub Module 2        Menu 4      Sub Menu D
```

I added each column separately earlier using the below cypher.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS--l-vqnnczvbr8gJnU4MlDwNB0LAsSnOvpsq4Zh0c6Ynyy8JHcpxQc7FEcpTXLSq3-DoQ688a3_/pub?gid=1169333354&single=true&output=csv" AS line
MERGE(s:SubMenu{id: TOINTEGER(line.SubMenuID), name:line.SubMenu_Name})
ON CREATE SET s.name = line.SubMenu_Name
```

However, I was looking to ingest the entire spreadsheet as is and establish the nodes with different labels and relationships.

Comment: Please edit to explain more about what your desired graph model is supposed to look like, vs what you're ending up with. Right now, it's unclear what specific issue you're running into.

Comment: Primary Goal - to create the application that I use into a knowledge graph. I have got the application inventory documented down to the field level in each Module, SubModule, Menu and SubMenu. I had separate spreadsheets for each label earlier. i need an quick approach to load the entire spreadsheet in one go. The query provided by helps with some corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Using `WITH` and some `MERGE` you can import the entire file. I don't see the need for the `ONE CREATE SET s.name =  line.SubMenu_Name` - the `MERGE` will anyway set it if it doesn't exist

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS--l-vqnnczvbr8gJnU4MlDwNB0LAsSnOvpsq4Zh0c6Ynyy8JHcpxQc7FEcpTXLSq3-DoQ688a3_/pub?gid=1169333354&single=true&output=csv" AS line
MERGE (m:Module {name: line.`Module`}) 
WITH m, line
MERGE (m)-[:SUB_MODULE]->(s:SubModule {name: line.`Sub-Module`})
WITH s, line
MERGE (s)-[:MENU]->(menu:Menu {name: line.`Menu`})
WITH menu, line
MERGE (menu)-[:SUB_MENU]->(submenu:SubMenu{id: TOINTEGER(line.nodeid), name:line.`Sub Menu`})
```

Comment: I corrected a typo and had another change based on the dataset. I ran into the error  'Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'id': (:SubMenu {id: null})'. I realized this was because of no values under Sub Menu for certain rows.  I updated the SubMenu value to 'NA' and removed id: TOINTEGER(line.nodeid) reference in the query and it worked. The SubMenu is going to be have empty cells, is there an approach in the query that would ignore the empty cells without having to update the empty cells with 'NA' as a value.

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTlOK8lOIzMR1E6YB-KDS4noHUZf_IYwavkoL8Ay8smAo9QYgxxED3Pq3JH2XpHcjndL8wqSrd/pub?output=csv" AS line
MERGE (m:Module {name: line.Module}) 
WITH m, line
MERGE (m)-[:SUB_MODULE]->(s:SubModule {name: line.SubModule})
WITH s, line
MERGE (s)-[:MENU]->(menu:Menu {name: line.Menu})
WITH menu, line
MERGE (menu)-[:SUB_MENU]->(submenu:SubMenu{ name:line.SubMenu})

Comment: a `WHERE` clause should take care of that, 
`...WITH menu, line WHERE line.SubMenu IS NOT NULL...`  is the last `WITH`

Comment: MERGE (s)-[:CONTAINS_MENU]->(m:Menu {name: line.Menu})
WITH m, line
WHERE line.SubMenu IS NOT NULL
MERGE (m)-[:CONTAINS_SUB_MENU]->(sm:SubMenu{name:line.SubMenu})
WITH sm, line
WHERE line.Screen IS NOT NULL
MERGE (sm)-[:LAUNCHES_SCREEN]->(s:Screen{name:line})....  This give me the error below.

Comment: This give me an error Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof. Encountered: Map{Panel -> String("Search"), Menu -> String("Block Status"), SubModule -> String("Booking"), SubMenu -> String("Status Codes"), Button -> NO_VALUE, Field -> NO_VALUE, SubScreen -> NO_VALUE, Mandatory Field -> NO_VALUE, Screen -> String("Status Codes"), NodeID -> String("115"), Module -> String("Administration")} -- The details of the application is divided as columns. The flow detailed in the spreadsheet leave many cells without a value for every row. How can this be ingested into Neo4j?

Comment: If you can post a sample file and your entire query I can take a look

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRj_9kyc9mWqxZJTcmb2w2PUGwAdRgHJTy-EgrIE_jJq0RjGKRuYl40nsc-Jd_6F3SyBThzjVBwmQSH/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv   [this is the link to the same sheet. appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: Ah! Took me long to see this one. Do you mean `->(s:Screen{name:line})` in the last bit. Shouldn't it be `>(s:Screen{name:line.Screen})` ?

Comment: yes. that is correct. it was a few of them that i had input incorrectly that failed the query. Thank you! appreciate your time and knowledge